# why = is optional in def in Scala

Tags: scala

Both of the following function definations compile even though one uses `=` and other doesn't. Why? Is there an advantage of this behaviour?

def 1

```
def doWork(index:Int) = {
        sleep((math.random*1000).toLong);
        index;
    }
```

def 2

```
def doWork(index:Int) {
        sleep((math.random*1000).toLong);
        index;
    }
```

Comment: Ran some tests on [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/). Your def 2 (procedure syntax) is not currently supported in the Dotty compiler and may not survive to Scala 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not including an `=` sign declares a [procedure](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#procedures). Procedures return `Unit`, i.e., don't return a value at all. As explained in the Scala language specification (from the link above):

> A procedure definition is a function definition where the result type and the equals sign are omitted; its defining expression must be a block. E.g., `def f(ps) {stats}` is equivalent to `def f(ps): Unit = {stats}`.

In your second case, the return value simply gets suppressed to turn a function that returns `Int` into a procedure that returns `Unit`. While doing so, the compiler should issue a warning similar to

```
warning: a pure expression does nothing in a statement position
```

This should let you know that something fishy is going on, i.e., there is a statement that would normally result in the block returning a value (`index;` in your case), but it goes unused.

Answer (score 2):

def 1 is what you want to use.

def 2 is called procedure syntax (discouraged) and actually means this:

```
def doWork(index:Int): Unit = {
    sleep((math.random*1000).toLong)
    index
}
```

So it's probably now what you want (since it doesn't return anything).

Answer (score 1):

When you don't use `"="` with def, it means your defined function will return unit.

And in the second function, you don't use `"="`, that means the defined function will return unit, but your function is returning index.
That's why it throws warning as it expects unit and discard the value.

Thanks

Comment: No, it won't and it doesn't throw an error, but a warning.